# Converting an ncat command on Windows from a Mac/Nix example

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, netcat, google-cloud-healthcare, google-healthcare-api

I'm working with the Google Healthcare API and there's a step in the walk through that uses netcat to send an HL7 message to the MLLP adapter.

*(I used nmap to download ncat for Windows)*

I have the adapter running locally but the command they provide is written for Mac/Nix users and I'm on Windows.

```
echo -n -e "\x0b$(cat hl7.txt)\x1c\x0d" | nc -q1 localhost 2575 | less
```

So I tried rewriting this for windows powershell:

```
$hl7 = type hl7.txt
Write-Output "-n -e \x0b" $hl7 "\x1c\x0d" | ncat -q1 localhost 2575 | less
```

When I try this, I get an error that "less" is invalid and also -q1 is also an invalid command.

If I remove `-q1` and `| less` the command executes with no output or error message.

I'm wondering if I'm using ncat incorrectly here or the write-output incorrectly?

**What is the -q1 parameter?**

It doesn't seem to be a valid ncat parameter from what I've researched.

I've been following this walkthrough:
https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#connection_refused_error_when_running_locally

Comment: I think that the `-q1` parameter is used for waiting 1 second and quit as explained [here](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/nc.htm). Not sure how you could adapt this waiting on the Powershell side.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need to follow the [tutorial for testing locally](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/how-tos/mllp-adapter#testing_the_mllp_adapter_locally_as_a_receiver) on a Windows Machine? Are you facing any difficulties with the Google Healthcare API itself?

Comment: @janiel - you need to use MLLP to send HL7 messages to the Healthcare API.  Once I got it to work locally I was going to then deploy the MLLP adapter Google uses to a Kubernates cluster

Comment: @DanielOcando - gotcha, I think in windows -w1 would wait for 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

We're really converting the echo command, not the ncat command.  The syntax for ascii codes is different in powershell.

```
[char]0x0b + (get-content hl7.txt) + [char]0x1c + [char]0x0d | 
  ncat -q1 localhost 2575
```

in ascii:  0b vertical tab, 1c file seperator, 0d carriage return http://www.asciitable.com

Or this.  `v is 0b and `r is 0d

```
"`v$(get-content hl7.txt)`u{1c}`r" | ncat -q1 localhost 2575
```

If you want it this way, it's the same thing.  All three ways end up being the same.

```
"`u{0b}$(get-content hl7.txt)`u{1c}`u{0d}" | ncat -q1 localhost 2575
```

Comment: I think HL7 messaging requires the certain characters to start and end, so perhaps the answer is:
"-n -e \x0b$(get-content hl7.txt)\x1c\x0d"